# Jobs in other SSH session

Tags: unix

Imagine this situation, I open an ssh session, in that session I start a process and put it on background, with `&` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, then I close this session. There is some way to open another session and put this process in the foreground? since the job don't exists anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `screen`. For example you could start with:

```
#> screen -S system-upgrade
#> aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade

[aptitude output here]
```

The you can press `Ctrl+A` and then `D` to `detach` the screen. From now on, you can re-`attach` the detached screen wherever you want on the same machine (e.g. another console, terminal, ssh session, etc.).

You simply need to type `screen -r system-upgrade` (where `system-upgrade` is just the leabel you originally gave to the screen).

```
#> screen -ls
There are screens on:
[SCREEN_PID].system-upgrade (Detached)

#> screen -r system-upgrade
[aptitude output here]
[new aptitude output from where you left detaching the screen]
```

Try it yourself, `screen` it's a really must-have package.

```
sudo aptitude install screen
```

Comment: Sorry, I took for granted that you were using a Debian-like distribution. Too much time spent on Askubuntu I suppose :)

Comment: that's ok, I'm using fedora but I got the idea. Thanks